# Baked block hash information on smart-contracts

Tags: tezos-client, michelson, blockchain, hash, random

It seems the passed baked blocks hashes are not available on-chain in LIGOLang or Michelson. Why is that and will it come later ?

Comment: I think it was never necessary on Tezos. But it would probably be useful for light clients. What would be your use case?

Comment: Getting asynchronous randomness values on-chain for example.

Comment: The block hash would not be a good source for randomness for projects where a successful attack was worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this does not answer my question why all this technical data is non-available.
Furthermore, we could use a pseudo-random value for any project without direct money incentive for example. There is many other potential use cases.